# Handling input data quality with checks & default value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a code for squaring the user input number in Python. I've created function my1() ...

What I want to do is to make Python to take user input of a number and square it but if user added no value it gives a print statement and by default give the square of a default number for e.g 2

Here is what I've tried so far

```
def my1(a=4):
 if my1() is None:
    print('You have not entered anything')
 else:
    b=a**2
    print (b)

my1(input("Enter a Number"))
```

Comment: What is the logic behind `if my1() is None:` ?

Comment: What is the queation here? Are you getting a error in this code

Comment: "Not hearing the question, son"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting an infinite loop by calling my1() within my1(). I would make the following edits:

```
def my1(a):
    if a is '':
        print('You have not entered anything')
    else:
        b=int(a)**2
        print (b)

my1(input("Enter a Number"))
```

Comment: Waaow this helped

Answer (score 2):

This is a better solution:

```
def my1(a=4):
    if not a:
        return 'You have not entered anything'
    else:
        try:
            return int(a)**2
        except ValueError:
            return 'Invalid input provided'

my1(input("Enter a Number"))
```

**Explanation**

- Have your function `return` values, instead of simply printing. This is good practice.
- Use `if not a` to test if your string is empty. This is a Pythonic idiom.
- Convert your input string to numeric data, e.g. via `int`.
- Catch `ValueError` and return an appropriate message in case the user input is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

In your second line, it should be 
    if a is None:

I think what you want to do is something like the following:

```
def m1(user_input=None):
    if user_input is None or isinstance(user_input, int):
        print("Input error!")
        return 4
    else:
        return int(user_input)**2
print(my1(input("Input a number")))
```

Comment: Instead of `type(a) != int`, I would have done `isinstance(a, int)`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, is there an actual benefit for doing the other way?

Comment: [From this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance), in short, and I quote it : `It's not that isinstance is good, mind you—it's just less bad than checking equality of types`. The Pythonic way to handle this case would `try/except` statement.

Answer (score 0):

When I read your code, I can see that you are very confused about what you are writing. Try to organize your mind around the **tasks** you'll need to perform. Here, you want to :

1. Receive your user inputs.
2. Compute the data.
3. Print accordingly.

First, take your input.

```
user_choice = input("Enter a number :")
```

Then, compute the data you received.

```
my1(user_choice)
```

You want your function, as of now, to `print an error message if your type data is not good`, else print the squared number.

```
def my1(user_choice): # Always give meaning to the name of your variables.
    if not user_choice:
        print 'Error'
    else:
        print user_choice ** 2
```

Here, you are basically saying "If my user_choice doesn't exists...". Meaning it equals `False` (it is a bit more complicated than this, but in short, you need to remember this). An empty string doesn't contain anything for instance. The other choice, `else`, is if you handled your error case, then your input must be right, so you compute your data accordingly.